# React appending

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, use-state

my question is and I am probably going about this wrong but I have statefull object to hold a property of name: that when the user writes a name for it is saved in the object as type name. That works but i need to have the ability to create another also of type name in the same objct.

this is how I am initializing my state

```
const [deptData, setDeptData] = useState({
        name: ''
    })
```

this is how implementing the first value collected which works

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
        let value = e.target.value;
        setDeptData({name: value})
    }
```

Then on the second create I have this which is overriding my previous value.

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
        let value = e.target.value;
        setDeptData({...deptData, name: value})
```

I want to capture as let departments = [
{
"name": "name1",
},
{
"name": "name1",
},
{
"name": "name1",
},
{
...
},
{
...
},
...
]

any help on this will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setDeptData({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

where

```
<input onchange={handleChange} name={'your_name1_here'} />
<input onchange={handleChange} name={'your_name2_here'} />
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can have two keys with the same name...instead you can try creating a database that will be an array of objects which will hold data of multiple users if that's what you were aiming for

Comment: Sorry I wasnt as clear the purpose i am trying to do is I have company , the user is creating a department for that company but they can do multiple departments at a time and are just trying to capture all the new values in a single object